# Login with Salesforce for 3rd party app

Tags: single-sign-on, identity

I have a web application that I'd like to place a 'Login with Salesforce' button on. I have many users in my application who are all part of different Salesforce orgs. I'd use the Salesforce Account Name as the unique identifier for my application.

EDIT: I should also specify that my app is NOT built on force.com - it is a custom .NET application.

My questions are:

- Is there a way to enable this button without needing to configure something in every specific org, and if so, how?
- If I do have configure something in every specific org, it looks like there are a few options on how to handle authentication - SAML 2.0, OpenID Connect, and OAuth2. I understand why you shouldn't use OAuth2, but is there an advantage to using SAML vs. OpenID Connect?

Thank you.

Comment: Why shouldn't you use OAuth2?

Comment: Check out https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Inside_OpenID_Connect_on_Force.com - specifically, "Why Not Just Use OAuth2?"

Comment: Just to add some clarity on that, it took me a few minutes to think through what the article was talking about, because it's pretty vague around how BadApp gains access to GoodApp resources. If GoodApp has an endpoint that takes in an OAuth2 token issued by ProviderApp and uses that as a login mechanism to GoodApp, BadApp can suddenly log in as any user to GoodApp who it has an access token for.